# Cannot generate pdf when currency is INR

Tags: ofbiz

Not sure what Im missing here and would love some help or guidance.

Im running ofbiz-12.04.05 and I've changed the default currency from USD to INR. Ive created a new Invoice but when I try to generate a .pdf it is failing with the below error.

Please help.

The Following Errors Occurred:
Unable to transform FO file: org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: -1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Logs:
==> error.log <==
2015-05-06 10:16:33,197 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443-exec-79) [ScreenFopViewHandler.java:121:ERROR] Unable to transform FO file: org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: -1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1; Screen XSL:FO text was:

==> fop.log <==
2015-05-06 10:16:33,194 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443-exec-79) [LoggingEventListener.java:80 :WARN ] Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".

==> ofbiz.log <==
2015-05-06 10:16:33,194 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443-exec-79) [LoggingEventListener.java:80 :WARN ] Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
2015-05-06 10:16:33,197 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443-exec-79) [ScreenFopViewHandler.java:121:ERROR] Unable to transform FO file: org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: -1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1; Screen XSL:FO text was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Begin Template component://common/webcommon/includes/reportTemplate.fo.ftl -->
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="main-page"
              page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in"
              margin-top="0.4in" margin-bottom="0.4in"
              margin-left="0.6in" margin-right="0.4in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="0.4in"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1.2in"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.4in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="main-page-landscape"
              page-width="11in" page-height="8.5in"
              margin-top="0.4in" margin-bottom="0.4in"
              margin-left="0.6in" margin-right="0.4in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1.2in" margin-bottom="0.4in"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1.2in"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.4in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main-page">

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(50)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="proportional-column-width(50)"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
<!-- Begin Template component://order/webapp/ordermgr/order/companyHeader.fo.ftl -->

<fo:block text-align="left">
    <fo:external-graphic src="/images/ofbiz_logo.gif" overflow="hidden" height="40px" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="2.00in"/>
</fo:block>

<fo:block font-size="8pt">
    <fo:block>Global Spice Trading Partners</fo:block>

            <!-- Begin Template component://party/webapp/partymgr/party/contactmechtemplates/PostalAddress_USA.fo.ftl -->
  <fo:block>2003 Open Blvd</fo:block>

  <fo:block>Open City, CA 999999</fo:block>
    <fo:block>
      United States
    </fo:block>
<!-- End Template component://party/webapp/partymgr/party/contactmechtemplates/PostalAddress_USA.fo.ftl -->


    <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts=".5in">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:block>Tax ID:</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>12-3456789</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:block>Email:</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>ofbiztest@example.com</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</fo:block>
<!-- End Template component://order/webapp/ordermgr/order/companyHeader.fo.ftl -->

                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
<!-- Begin Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportHeaderInfo.fo.ftl -->
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
<fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="2.5in"/>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block number-columns-spanned="2" font-weight="bold">Sales Invoice</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Inv. Date:</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>May 4, 2015</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Cust.Nr:</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>10000</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>


<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Inv.Nr:</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>CI3</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Descr:</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>pepps</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>

<!--fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Status</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell><fo:block font-weight="bold">In-Process</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row-->
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
<!-- End Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportHeaderInfo.fo.ftl -->

                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="center" space-before="10pt">
                Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="theEnd"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<!-- Begin Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportContactMechs.fo.ftl -->
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-after="0.3in">
   <fo:table-column column-width="3.5in"/>
    <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row >
        <fo:table-cell>
               <fo:block>To: </fo:block>
        <fo:block>No general/billing address found for party:10000</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
<!-- End Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportContactMechs.fo.ftl -->
<!-- Begin Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportItems.fo.ftl -->


    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-before="0.2in">
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="85mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>

    <fo:table-header height="14px">
      <fo:table-row border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="thin" border-bottom-color="black">
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block font-weight="bold">Product</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block font-weight="bold">Description</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">Qty</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">Unit Price</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">Amount</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>


    <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">

        <fo:table-row height="7px">
            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="5"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>

        <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
              <fo:block/>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
              <fo:block font-weight="bold">TOTAL</fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell text-align="right" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="thin" border-top-color="black">
              <fo:block>₹0.00</fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row height="7px">
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="5">
              <fo:block/>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row height="14px">
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
              <fo:block/>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
              <fo:block>Total excl. tax</fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell text-align="right" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="thin" border-top-color="black">
              <fo:block>
₹0.00              </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
 </fo:table>



 <fo:block></fo:block>
<!-- End Template component://accounting/webapp/accounting/invoice/invoiceReportItems.fo.ftl -->

            <fo:block id="theEnd"/>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
<!-- End Template component://common/webcommon/includes/reportTemplate.fo.ftl -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `CURRENCY_UOM_ID` from `USD TO INR` in these tables:

- party_acctg_preference
- product_store
- product_price